# Probability of $\frac{1}{X}\leq t$ where $X$ is standard normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

> Let be $X$ a random variable that obeys a standard normal distribution and $t>0$. We exclude the set where $X$ attains $0$. Compute $P(\frac{1}{X}\leq t)$ and express it by the standard normal distribution function $\Phi$. Then, calculate $\lim\limits_{t\to0}P(\frac{1}{X}\leq t)$.

---

$$
\begin{align*}
P(\frac{1}{X}\leq t)&=P(X\geq \frac{1}{t},X>0)+P(X\leq \frac{1}{t},X<0)\\&=\int\limits_{\frac{1}{t}}^{\infty}f_X(x)dx+\int\limits_{-\infty}^0f_X(x)dx\\&=1-\Phi\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)+\Phi(0).\end{align*}
$$

Now, we immediately see $\lim\limits_{t\to0}P(\frac{1}{X}\leq t)=\lim\limits_{t\to0}(1-\Phi\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)+\Phi(0))=\Phi(0)=\frac{1}{2}.$

Is this correct?

Comment: Seems correct to me, although you have calculated the right limit at $t=0$. I suggest you to also calculate the left limit at $t=0$ and complete the conclusion.

Comment: To put a fine point on Mostafa's comment, you should be able to recognize that every step after $P(\frac1X \leq t)$ assumed $t > 0$.  The expression for $t<0$ is not $1 - \Phi(1/t) + \Phi(0)$, as this would be $>1$, so to find the left-hand limit at $t=0$, you need to go back to $P(\frac1X \leq t)$ (or use the fact $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution, along with what you'd already shown).